# How do I disambiguate overriding virtuals from a repeatedly inherited base class?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Consider the following invalid C++ code.

```
#include <assert.h>

class NodeInterface {
public:
    virtual ~NodeInterface () {}

    virtual int f (const int& n) const = 0;
};

class ChildNodeInterface : public NodeInterface {
public:
    virtual ~ChildNodeInterface () {}
};

class ParentNodeInterface : public NodeInterface {
public:
    virtual ~ParentNodeInterface () {}
};

class ChildNode : public ChildNodeInterface {
public:
    virtual ~ChildNode () {}

    virtual int f (const int& n) const {
        return 2*n;
    }
};

class ParentNode : public ParentNodeInterface, private ChildNodeInterface {
public:
    explicit ParentNode () :
        mChild (new ChildNode ())
    {
    }

    virtual ~ParentNode () {}

    ChildNodeInterface* GetChildHandle () {
        return this;
    }

    virtual int f (const int& n) const {
        return 3*n;
    }

private:
    ChildNode* const mChild;

    // How do I specify that I would like to override ChildNodeInterface::f?
    virtual int f (const int& n) const { // On MSVC2010: C2535 member function already defined or declared
        return 1 + mChild->f (n);
    }
};

int main()
{
    ParentNode parent;
    assert (parent.f (2) == 6);
    ChildNode node;
    assert (node.f (2) == 4);
    ChildNodeInterface* child (parent.GetChildHandle ());
    assert (child->f (2) == 5);
    return 0;
}
```

It is my aim to make `ParentNode` privately look like a `ChildNode`, so that it can add some additional functionality on top of `ChildNode`'s implementation of `ChildNodeInterface`. `ParentNode` could thereby effectively be treated as a `ChildNode`-handle in disguise, indicated by the simplicity of `GetChildHandle`.
Clearly, if `ParentNode` would not repeatedly inherit from `NodeInterface`, there would be no problem. Since, one can then easily disambiguate the overrides. This is illustrated by the following correct example:

```
#include <assert.h>

class ChildNodeInterface {
public:
    virtual ~ChildNodeInterface () {}

    virtual int ChildMethod (const int& n) const = 0;
};

class ParentNodeInterface {
public:
    virtual ~ParentNodeInterface () {}

    virtual int ParentMethod (const int& n) const = 0;
};

class ChildNode : public ChildNodeInterface {
public:
    virtual ~ChildNode () {}

    virtual int ChildMethod (const int& n) const {
        return 2*n;
    }
};

class ParentNode : public ParentNodeInterface, private ChildNodeInterface {
public:
    explicit ParentNode () :
        mChild (new ChildNode ()),
        mValue (1)
    {
    }

    ChildNodeInterface* GetChildHandle () {
        return this;
    }

    virtual int ParentMethod (const int& n) const {
        return 3*n;
    }

private:
    ChildNode* const mChild;
    const int mValue;

    virtual int ChildMethod (const int& n) const {
        return mValue + mChild->ChildMethod (n);
    }
};

int main()
{
    ParentNode parent;
    assert (parent.ParentMethod (2) == 6);
    ChildNode node;
    assert (node.ChildMethod (2) == 4);
    ChildNodeInterface* child (parent.GetChildHandle ());
    assert (child->ChildMethod (2) == 5);
    return 0;
}
```

However, in the special case where `ParentNodeInterface` and `ChildNodeInterface` both inherit from `NodeInterface`, the ambiguity arises.
As should be clear from the assertions in `main`, I do not aim for virtual inheritance of `NodeInterface`. It is my intention to have truly distinct implementations of `NodeInterface::f` in `ParentNode`.
I wonder how (if possible) I can discriminate between the implementation of `ParentNodeInterface::f` and `ChildNodeInterface::f` in `ParentNode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your design is wrong. You are inherited ChildNodeInterface and you have a ChildNode member in your ParentNode Class?

Inherited ChildNodeInterface doesn't allow you to use f function implementation since ChildNode class is not in the inheritance tree.

Redifining twice a function with the same signature is not allowed by C++. So writing 2 implementation of the same virtual function can't be done.

So you have 2 options:

1. [Best] Try to redefine your class design using inheritance in the correct way. Diamond inheritance is often due to a bad design.
2. [Fastest] Remove inheritance from ChildNodeInterface and prefer calling mChild->f() in the ParentNode::f() function to add the Child behavior to the parent:

   virtual int f (const int& n) const
   {
       return 3*n + mChild->f(n);
   }
   But I don't know if it's the behavior you want.

Comment: You say that "Redefining twice a function with the same signature is not allowed by C++". I agree, but I don't understand why these virtuals have exactly the same signature. As seen from `ParentNode`, `f` occurs both publically and privately (which is a difference) and through either `ChildNodeInterface` or `ParentNodeInterface` (which is another difference).

Comment: As far as I know visibility is not a part of the signature. In ParentNode point of view the visibility is the same. In addition with diamond inheritance, you can't redefine a virtual function from common base since compiler can't know from which path of inheritance comes the prototype. You have to do virtual inheritance do be able to do this kind of thing

Answer (score 1):

Note that `ChildNodeInterface` really has nothing to do with `ChildNode::f()`.

But to solve your problem (I think), instead of privately inheriting from `ChildNodeInterface`, use a helper type that inherits from `ChildNode` and override `ChildNode::f()` in that type.  `ParentNode` can maintain a pointer to one of those objects (or just have a plain old member of that type), and dole out the pointer to that thing when `ParentNode::GetChildHandle()` is called:

```
// the helper class
class ParentNode;
class ParentsChildNodeInterface : public ChildNode {
public:
    virtual int f (const int& n) const;
};

class ParentNode : public ParentNodeInterface {

public:
    explicit ParentNode () :
        mChild (new ParentsChildNodeInterface ())
    {
    }

    virtual ~ParentNode () {}

    ChildNodeInterface* GetChildHandle () {
        return mChild;
    }

    virtual int f (const int& n) const {
        return 3*n;
    }

private:
    ParentsChildNodeInterface* const mChild;
};

// the new, special f() for children of parents...
int ParentsChildNodeInterface::f (const int& n) const {
    return 1 + ChildNode::f (n);
}
```

As posted, the helper class doesn't need to access any state in the `ParentNode` object. But if it did need to, you could make the helper class a `friend` of `ParentNode`.

Comment: Indeed, a helper class would solve the problem, but then requires friendship to `ParentNode` to access state. This is undesirable. I've just added a working example to illustrate the purpose of this ordeal. One can see now that only the ambiguity by repeated inheritance of `NodeInterface` causes the problem.

Comment: The helper class is an implementation detail of `ParentNode`. Making the helper a `friend` might be undesirable in one sense, but it just reflects the fact that there's a close implantation relationship between them. You could strengthen the 'implementation detail' aspect by declaring the helper class inside `ParentNode` so it's private.  Or forward declare the helper class, mark it as a `friend` and put the entire implementation (including the helper class' definition) inside the `ParentNode.cpp` implementation file - nothing else would have any access to the helper class.